# Feature Selection with Ordinal, Categorical Nominal, and Continuous variables as predictor

Tags: classification, categorical-data, feature-selection, continuous

I am looking to classify loan defaulters i.e. 0 for non defaulter and 1 for defaulter from a dataset containing 13000+ rows and 162 predictor variables. The predictor variable consists of categorical ordinal, categorical nominal, and continuous variables along with Dummy variables.

As this is a classification problem, I am looking to apply Logistic Regression, SVM and Decision Trees. I am finding it difficult to run feature selection for such a varied pool of predictor variables. My first try is to segregate the categorical variables (clubbing ordinal and nominal together) and continuous variables, and select feature using Chi Square and Anova respectively.

I hope this explains the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running a cross tabulation among some of the features to find whether there is some correlation among the selected variables you have chosen to apply your cross tabulation on.
for instance , feature A and feature B seems to independently contribute to the dependent variable. While performing cross tabulation you may come across an interesting observation that feature A has a positive correlation with B thereby indicating that you can drop feature A from the table since we would be able to deduce feature A relevant values as long as we have feature B.
Sometimes a bit of cross tabulation can do wonders. Hope it helps

Comment: I checked the data type in Python, and the categorical variables are read as integer types because for example Var 11 is categorical in nature with values 1-5. Should I still go for cross tabulation as all of my variables are either integer or float now or should I use any continuous feature selection algorithm?

Comment: do you have more numbers of categorical variables or greater number of continous variables?

Comment: 79% of the variables are categorical and 21% is continuous